# Have there been cases in church history of revival occurring in times of prosperity and general peace?

Tags: church-history, society, divine-intervention, revival

In looking at historical cases of revival it seems like most seem to occur right in the midst of some disaster or general societal upheaval. Of course, the occasion for revival taking place shouldn't be confused with the source of revival. That would be a genetic fallacy. The source of revival is God and the power of his word. But if the occasion is important to remove obstacles for God to work than that's another story.

Answer (score 2):

In reflecting a bit more on my question, I think a good case can be made that when the Holy Spirit came down on the young people, on [Mother's Day  of 1980](https://gwmgracenotes.blogspot.com/2010/05/thirty-year-anniversary-of-mothers-day.html), at Calvary Chapel in Yorba Linda a revival was initiated that would eventually impact the Christian church in a positive way even more than the charismatic renewal of the turbulent 1960's.

Answer (score 1):

A good example is the [Second Great Awakening.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Great_Awakening) This happened during a relatively peaceful period of history, and had a great revival of spirituality and belief.

Comment: If I had more time I would say more. The link I provided has a lot of info